# I Submit an App to the App Store, How can I know the seller`s name it will appear?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

well I submit my app a few days ago, but I want to know how its going to appear in the app store, I mean the developers name, the problem is that I have 17 and I put all the stuff at my uncles name because I use his credit card, so the displayed name will be my uncles name? Or the one of the Provisioning Profile? Or the one of the copyright, because thats on my name.

So I need someones help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go here: [Developer Center Account Summary](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#accountSummary)

Whatever's listed as name in the 'Developer Account Summary' will appear as developer in app store.

Comment: Yes, I believe those are the names that will appear, 'Leopoldo Mayen Garcia'.  I can't imagine changing it would cause problems, but I hesitate to tell you its ok because I honestly don't know.  On another note, you should remove and delete that photo reference.  It contains a bit of personal information you might prefer to keep private (i.e. address)!

Comment: I doubt that you can change the name at all. Unless you legally changed your uncles name to yours. ;-) The account is not your account. If your uncle is okay with it release the apps under his name. Once you have your own account you can transfer the apps to your account.

Comment: MMM ok, and why some people can put nicknames instead of their real name??